# Disabling and unchecking a radiobutton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have 3 radiobuttons and one checkbox. I want to disable radio button 2 when the checkbox is unchecked. That works fine by using

```
 <RadioButton x:Name="rbButtton2" Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  GroupName="gnKind" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cbCheck, Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

BUT, I want that IF radio button 2 happens to be checked when the check box is unchecked, then uncheck it, then check radiobutton1 and disable it. How could I achieve that the best way?

Comment: "Which language" Xaml (c#)

Comment: If you have a proper data layer, you should be doing this using the PropertyChanged event of the data layer. If property changed is `BoundCheckBoxProperty` and `BoundCheckBoxProperty == false && BoundRadioButton2Property == true`, then set `BoundRadioButton2Property = false`. If you don't have a proper data layer, just using the code behind is fine. Or triggers as [this answer suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40267876/302677)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use triggers. You would basically use a MultiDataTrigger on IsEnabled=false and IsChecked=true and if it falls in there, the trigger would set IsChecked=false on button1 and IsChecked=true on button2.